# How to style the first and last li with CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I style the first (top level) `li` and the last (top level) `li` with CSS or jQuery?

I am using CSS to set the first `li` style but it is also styling the first `li` in each secondary level `ul`, so how can I get it to style only the `li` with Main 1 in it and the last one with Main 6 in it?

Here is my code:

```
<style>
ul li:first-child
{
width: 800px;
border:1px solid #fc5604; border-top-width:thin; (2px)
}
</style>
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1c</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main 6</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: For maximum cross browser compatibility you should add a class to the first and last list item and style them based on class.

Comment: @user520300 Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 37):

You have to use the [immediate child selector](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/):

```
ul > li:first-child
```

This rule will affect an `<li>` that is only immediately preceded by a `<ul>`.  This should apply to both jQuery and css.  Not all browsers can use the pseudo classes (especially `last-child`.

Comment: It's called the *[child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)*, not the "direct parent selector".

Answer (score 8):

The first item is quite simple, and I see you already have the `:first-child` down. `:last-child` does the same, but it has limited support in IE. However, if the number of list items are fixed (which it seems to me), you can actually target the last item with CSS alone. Observe!

```
li + li + li +li + li + li { background:pink; }
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgRZQ/1/

The `+` selector basically targets the immediate next sibling (if it matches your type), so it's a matter of counting your way to the last. And yes, this works in IE7. :)

Comment: Great tip.  For the sake of precision, it "targets the immediate next sibling**s**".

Answer (score 7):

Give a class name for first ul tag.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1c</a></li>
            </ul>...........
...................................
```

Then you can use like the following CSS:

```
<style>
ul.list > li:first-child{
width: 800px;
border:1px solid #fc5604; border-top-width:thin; (2px)
}
ul.list > li:last-child{
width: 800px;
border:1px solid #fc5604; border-top-width:thin; (2px)
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<style>
    ul > li:first-child, ul > li:last-child
    {
        width: 800px;
        border:1px solid #fc5604; border-top-width:thin; (2px)
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the `:last-child` selector isn't supported by Internet Explorer 8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use jQuery you could use the following:

```
$('#nav > ul li').first().css('background-color', 'red');
$('#nav > ul li').last().css('background-color', 'red');
```

^ should do the trick.

Comment: the last didnt work because probably the last li is actually the nested one but i need it to be the parent li

Comment: JS should be avoided for things where CSS offers an easy way to deal with the issue imho.