# Style the last DIV in a row of DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I checked this post ([How to style the first and last li with CSS or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896938/how-to-style-the-first-and-last-li-with-css-or-jquery)) but am still seeking a suitable IE8(and pre IE8) solution.

I have a row of DIVs that are set to have a padding-right, but in order for the final one to align properly want the final DIV to have zero padding. I've used the .css + .css route before but that doesn't appear to work in IE8 and versions before it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Appreciate the answers, a good selection of solutions. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. That's what we're here for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's a containing div wrapping all of these, you should be able to do this:

```
div.container {
    background-color: blue;
}
div.container .div-row {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
div.container .div-row:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give a class to last div and get it working with that class in IE.

```
<div class="last"></div>

<style>
    .last
    {
        padding-right:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is how we have solved this problem. We actually have different styles for both our first and last divs. We had to add the classes manually.

Comment: Also you can make this working with javascript, if there are more than one places to do the same work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following CSS:

```
.rowofdivs div:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user css pseudo-class `:last-of-type`

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS3 selector, see [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for a list of whats available to what browsers.

Why don't you add a class="last" to last div in code?

last-child is not available for IE8 and less

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot manually add the "last" class as suggested in other answers, you will have to rely on JavaScript to accomplish this. If you have jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
 $('#parentdiv div:last-child').addClass('last');
```

Then adjust your stylesheet accordingly:

```
 .last { padding-right: 0 }
```